# Connecting Azure SQL database using managed identity from container instance

Tags: r, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-container-instances

I want to connect Azure SQL server instance using managed identity from Container Instance application which is running R script on ubuntu container.

Currently I am using DBI package with odbc driver to connect using SQL login, but would like to get rid off using separate SQL logins for apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign System-Assigned Managed Identity for your Container Instance

Go to your Azure Container Instance --> Select Identity under Settings --> Enable System-Assigned status as ON and click on save

Go to your Azure SQL server --> Select Access Control --> Select Add Role Assignment --> Select your Container Instance Object --> Assign the required role

Now, you can use Managed Identity to connect to Azure SQL database from your container instance

You do not need to provide any additional credentials

You can use **get_managed_token()** in your script to connect to Azure SQL Database

By default, **get_managed_token** retrieves a token using the system-assigned identity for the resource.

Comment: After some research it seems that this is not possible at the moment as R odbc is not supporting preconnection attributes required by token based authentication. So I guess I just have to wait until this feature is implemented.

https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/299